# C# ASP.NET MVC 5 How to execute a raw query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity

I am trying to execute a raw query using c#.

Here is what I have done

```
var accounts = conn.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<string>>("SELECT TOP 1 a.* FROM zipcodes_to_accounts AS c " +
"INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.id = c.account_id " +
"WHERE c.zip_code = @p0 "+
"ORDER BY a.completed_ll + a.completed_cp ASC", zipcode).ToArray();
```

Then I want to take the first record and convert it to json object.

```
if (accounts.Count() > 0)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject( accounts.First() ); 
}
```

But the query is giving me an error

> The result type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor.

The accounts table has some columns that are varchar, datetime, integers. How can I get this query to work?

**UPDATED**
Converting the `IEnumerable` to list like advised in the answer it working. but now the `JsonConvert` is returning an empty object. Here is my current code

```
       //getAccount
        public string GetAccount()
        {


            string zipcode = StringHelpers.StringOrNull(Request["zip_code"]);

            if (zipcode != null)
            {

                var accounts = conn.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>("SELECT TOP 1 a.* FROM zipcodes_to_accounts AS c " +
"INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.id = c.account_id "+
"WHERE c.zip_code = @p0 "+
"ORDER BY a.completed_ll + a.completed_cp ASC", zipcode).ToList();
                var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

                if (firstAccount != null)
                {
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(firstAccount);
                }

            }

            return "{}";

        }
```

When I debug my code Here is what I see

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what ORM you're using, but the warning is telling you that IEnumerable cannot be constructed as it's an interface. Therefore the `SqlQuery` method can't know what return type you're expecting.

Try replacing the generic constraint with a concrete type:

```
var accounts = conn.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT TOP 1 a.* FROM zipcodes_to_accounts AS c " +
"INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.id = c.account_id " +
"WHERE c.zip_code = @p0 "+
"ORDER BY a.completed_ll + a.completed_cp ASC", zipcode).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm! I will accept your answer when time permits.

Comment: One issue that am I having is that the query is returning 1 record but the JsonConvert is converting it into an empty object i.e. `[]` I am not sure if this is relevant to this question or not but do you have an idea on why it is returning and empty object? I will update my question with my current code

Comment: @MikeA Check the contents of `firstAccount`, is it empty?

Comment: I am not really sure how to tell. I am not to C# and VS. but when I set a breaking point and run the script into debugging mode accounts count is 1then first
AccountCount is 0. I am going to update my question with a screenshot to show you what I am seeing

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `if (firstAccount != null)` then hover your mouse on `firstAccount`. The value of the variable will be displayed

Comment: I did that. all I get is count = 0 please check the screenshot in my question

Comment: @MikeA I see. My bad, my answer was wrong. You need to use `string` as generic constraint, not `List<string>` (see my edit)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104582/discussion-between-mike-a-and-kookiz).

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for a `IEnumerable<string>` which is an interface. You need to pick a class that implements `IEnumerable` such as a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)